# how to go on to play music one by one automatically in R?

Tags: r

I want to play all the mp3  musics in my computer.

```
list.files(c("c:/","d:/","e:/"),pattern="mp3",full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)->x
library(tuneR)
sapply(x,function(y){play(y)})
```

there is a little problem ,when one music was played ,i had to close the mplayer window and the next music will be played ,but when it finished ,i had to clode the mplayer window again,
how can i make it play  automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official documentation of tuneR package says that 
in function

`play(object, player, ...)`

> If no player and no further
>   arguments are given under Windows, the default is: "/play /close".

So it should work. But if it doesn't, maybe you should specify another player than mplayer?